# How to preload fonts in nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt3

In `nuxt 2` we added this in `nuxt.config.js`

```
 link: [
    
      {
        rel: 'preload',
        type: 'font/woff2',
        href: '/fonts/font.woff2',
        as: 'font',
        crossorigin: true
      },
```

I can't find any info how to do the same in `nuxt 3`.
I need the fonts not to jump when the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the [`app.vue`](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/app) file via the [`useHead`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head) composable:

```js
<script setup>

useHead({
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'preload',
      type: 'font/woff2',
      href: '/fonts/font.woff2',
      as: 'font',
      crossorigin: true
    },
)}

</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work. I get typescript error as well
 "Argument type {link: ({crossorigin: true, as: "font", rel: "preload", href: string, type: "font/woff"} | {crossorigin: true, as: "font", rel: "preload", href: string, type: "font/woff"})[]} is not assignable to parameter type UseHeadInput<MergeHead> "

Comment: oh, I imported useHead not from unhead. Now it seems it should work but I see the warning in console "The resource source.com/font.woff was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally." May because it's localhost.